# How does typecasting SOQL records to Map<Id, SObjects> maintains the order?

Tags: apex, map, sortorder

As we know we can typecaste SOQL results to a List, or Map.

`List` we all know is Ordered thus, can maintain the order.

`Map` we know its always unordered because the `keys` of a map is `Set`

So if I do something like this.

```
Map<Id, Account> mapOfAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM Account ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 10]);

for(Id eachAccountId : mapOfAccounts.keySet()){
    System.debug(mapOfAccounts.get(eachAccountId).CreatedDate);
}
```

how does Apex maintain the order even in a Map?

Comment: There's no explicit specification of this, just that `values` and `keySet` provide deterministic orders. I have observed ordering by order of insertion into the map (and one might assume this conversion iterates from 0 upward), but this is not guaranteed.